# ExtJS 3.2.1 Combobox drop down set value if exists

Tags: extjs3

ExtJS 3.2.1

I have a **Combobox drop down menu called "location"** on the left panel along with other menu drop downs. **Main panel is a grid** and is displaying on the right side.

On `CheckboxSelectionModel`, `rowselect listeners`, I am setting value of the location drop down based value from the main grid row location value.

Sometimes, a location may be disabled so left menu wont display that location. But the same location was previously added when it was active and the main grid row has that value. how to I check the `combobox drop down` value if `grid row` data location exists? If not exists, I can display the default text.

Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer.

if (Ext.getCmp('location').store.find('locationid', '00000') != -1) //exists

00000 - locationid to search